# Create CMS Page from installer - Magento

Tags: php, magento

I have this data-upgrade-0.0.x-0.0.x+1.php data install file inside my installer with that code:

```
 <?php
$cmsPage = Array ( 
    'title' => 'Test Page 1', 
    'identifier' => 'testpage1', 
    'content' => '<p>Testowa sprawa</p>', 
    'is_active' => '1', 
    'stores' => array(1), 
    'root_template' => 'one_column', 
    );




Mage::getModel('cms/block')->setData($cmsPage)->save();
```

And there is no effect for that, is the syntax correct ?

Comment: Are you sure your installscript was executed? Does store 1 exist? Else it looks fine.

Comment: Ok it is fine. Noob mistake i just call file data-update and it should be data-upgrade :-)

I have got another question. When page with the same 'identifier' already exist, installer make another with the same identifier. Is there a way to get him to make update ?

Comment: Sure. Please update your question or post a new one and I'm happy to answer it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21748879/how-to-update-existing-cms-page-through-install-script