# How to update existing cms page through install script

Tags: php, magento

I have this script

```
$cmsPage = Array ( 
    'title' => 'Test Page 1',
    'root_template' => 'one_column', 
    'identifier' => 'testpage1', 
    'content' => "<p>Testowa sprawa czy działa update ? oooooooooooo</p>", 
    'is_active' => 1,
    'stores' => array(1), 
    'sort_order' => 0 
);
$collection = Mage::getModel('cms/page')->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('identifier', 'testpage1');
$page = Mage::getModel('cms/page')->load($collection->getFirstItem()->getId());
$page->setData($cmsPage)->save();
```

If cms page with identifier "testpage1" exist , the script create another with the same identifier. Is there a way to check if cmspage exist - and if that is true - do update ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you call `$page->setData($cmsPage)` you remove all data from the `Mage_Cms_Model_Page` object and replace it with the data from the `$cmsPage` array.  Part of the data you are removing is the `page_id` from the object's internal `$_data` array.  The `page_id` is what maps the object to a column in the `cms_page` database table.  By removing that ID you make Magento run an `INSERT` query rather than an `UPDATE`.

Something like this should work:

```
$pageId = $collection = Mage::getModel('cms/page')->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('identifier', 'testpage1')->getFirstItem()->getId();
$page = Mage::getModel('cms/page')->load($pageId);

$cmsPage = Array ( 
    'page_id' => $pageId,
    'title' => 'Test Page 1',
    'root_template' => 'one_column', 
    'identifier' => 'testpage1', 
    'content' => "<p>Testowa sprawa czy działa update ? oooooooooooo</p>", 
    'is_active' => 1,
    'stores' => array(1), 
    'sort_order' => 0 
);

$page->setData($cmsPage)->save();
```

Comment: Ok, it works fine ! But as always, i got another question :-)
What if we have couple of static pages with the same identifier (for expample with other store view (multistore)) - how can i filter identifier and store togather (store is stored in cms/page_store)

Comment: Have a read of `Mage_Cms_Model_Resource_Page_Collection::addStoreFilter()`.  It looks like you will be able to do something like `Mage::getModel('cms/page')->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('identifier', 'testpage1')->addStoreFilter(array('storeid1', 'storeid2'), true);`.  Check the function out for more info on the params.